# My material is shown in preview but does not appear in object or render view

Tags: node-editor, blender-internal-render-engine

[image]When I tried using tutorials to assign randomized color on each polygon, they don't seem to appear in the object mode and render mode. I've tried two methods. one, I used one method found online https://blenderartists.org/t/quick-tip-easy-randomize-face-color-with-cycles/627580 , in a forum someone was kind enough to post (but I suck so it didn't work :P). Two, I started using the method I found on youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kBrOzCxOWhM but as soon as I started to use the node editor, I didnt see immediate change in my object. For both instances, I could see that the preview mode in the material tab showed the material that I wanted but was not applied into my object. I am fairly new at using blender so I don't really know where I went wrong. If you can help me, that would be great! Thank you.

Comment: You are in Solid view. The circle at the top of the screen, change this to LookDev or Rendered, the cartoon 3d sphere and the full 3d sphere next to it. Or press Z to get a Pie menu to change.

Comment: Oh wow thank you thank you! I feel a bit silly :P but I'm glad there wasn't anything wrong with my material. I wasn't used to blender 2.8 so i didnt know many of the settings.

Comment: THanks for the fast reply!